# Why Peek and Read use integers to warn you about the end of file instead of exceptions to check end of streamreader in C#?

Tags: c#, streamreader

I and writing a very simple C# class to read all the chars of a UTF8 file.

For the main loop, the condition to detect the end of file is:

```
while (!fin.EndOfStream) 
{
    int c = fin.Read();
    <some text processing>
}
```

But I know a least two other ways to do it:

```
while (fin.Peek() >= 0)
{
    int c = fin.Read();
    <some text processing>
}
```

And:

```
int c = 0;
while ((c = fin.Read()) >= 0) 
{
   <some text processing>
}
```

For me the first form is the best: is shorter, is clearer, the condition is pretty simple to understand and you don't have to know that Read() or Peek() returns -1 when you reach the end of file.

Besides the second and third form don't follow the information hiding principle(Wikipedia quote): 
[Information Hiding principle.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding)

My question is:

Why there are so many ways to check the end of file?

Why spend time and resources designing, coding, testing and maintaining so many ways to check the end of file?

Edit:

Read and Peek warn you about the end of file, and you can use them to do the work that EndOfStream is supossed to do. What I mean is: Read and Peek are doing their own work and the work of EndOfStream so Read and Peek are doing more work that their name suggest. Instead of integers, exceptions could be used whenever the end of file is reached.

Comment: `Peek` and especially `Read` have uses besides checking for EOF, though they *can* be used to to do that. Whats wrong with that? What would you have `Read` return at EOF? I don't think this question is really answerable.

Comment: Side note: calling `StreamReader` "stream" is potentially confusing. Please consider explicitly specifying types in your future questions.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of your question is wrong.

All of those functions have different semantics, different purposes. Just because they are interchangeable in one context, it doesn't mean you can do it freely in every context. Only one of the methods is designed specifically to check for end of the stream - `fin.EndOfStream`.

Just because people use baseball bats for hitting other people, it doesn't mean baseball bats are redundant and useless because there are other (even better) ways to do it. They have its purpose in different contexts.

One could actually argue (at least in my opinion), that `fin.EndOfStream` might be redundant to `(fin.Peek() >= 0)`, or the language designers could have made it so, however they decided to allow programs to be semantically clean. Checking for the end of stream feels more natural than peeking for the next character expecting an error.

Existence of each method and property you talk about is justified.

Comment: If anyone will ever wonder. The edit made the answer hardly related.

Answer (score 0):

`Peek` is equal to a `Read` without affecting the state of the stream, so I wouldn't count that as an 'alternative'. There are a few other classes that provide `Peek` and `Read` options.

There are also other classes that use `Read` to both read and notify about the end of the stream, `XmlReader` for instance which returns a `bool` instead of a number.

I agree with you that using a *number* as indication whether the end is reached is odd. The return value of `Read` at the end of the stream by the way is 0, not -1, and when data is not available *yet* the stream is documented to block until data is available (because if it would return 0, it would mean the end of the stream). They could have chosen `bool TryRead(..., out int bytes)` instead.

I don't how decisions were made regarding `Stream`, but if it satisfies your question we could pretend they thought exactly as you did and created an `EndOfStream` property for people who didn't like the other approach. A sort of evidence for this is that implementers of `Stream` don't have to implement `EndOfStream`, because it simply represents the status of the last `Read` operation.

Comment: Note that OP made question confusing by mixing up "stream" and `StreamReader`... `Stream` does not even have `Peek`.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't even check, I spend my days in .NET CF 2.0 or if I'm lucky 3.5, and simply assumed they were added in 4. Thanks for pointing that out.